# python remove a tuple of keys from a list of attribute dicts

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to remove a tuple of keys from a list of `AttributeDictionary`, called `att_dict_list`

```
dict_list = [dict(att_dict.pop(k, None) for k in ('a', 'b', 'e')) for att_dict in att_dict_list]
```

`AttributeDictionary` class is defined as

```
class AttributeDictionary(dict, json_mixin.JsonMixin):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(AttributeDictionary, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.attr1 = []
        return obj

    def __init__(self, manager=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttributeDictionary, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

        if manager:
            self.process_safe_dict = manager.dict()

    def has(self, obj_name):
        return obj_name in list(self.__dict__.keys())
```

but got error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

an example `AttributeDictionary` in `att_dict_list` are defined as,

```
  {'a': [[ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e2266f0d62b'),
   2018600046.0],
  [ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e2266f0d62a'), 2010600047.0]],
  'b': [[ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e2257f0ccbd'),
   2011601057.0],
  [ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e2257f0bde3'), 2019601058.0]],
  'e': [
  [[ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e2257f0ccbd'), 2019601057.0],
   [ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e2257f0bde3'), 2019601058.0]],
  [[ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e225cf0b240'), 2014601177.0],
   [ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e225cf0b23f'), 2013601178.0]],
  [[ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e225cf0bc4c'), 2012601192.0],
   [ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e225cf0bc4b'), 2011601193.0]],
  [[ObjectId('5a8ec91ef1c63e225cf0cb09'), 2013601216.0]]
  ],
  'f': 109,
  'c': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  'd': [2010601086.0, 2011601085.0, 2012601084.0]
  }
```

and say I want to delete keys `a`, `b`, `e`.

full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-d4b38cb7b048>", line 4, in <module>
for att_dict in att_dict_list]
  File "<ipython-input-3-d4b38cb7b048>", line 4, in <listcomp>
for att_dict in att_dict_list]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I am wondering how to solve the issue.

Comment: What is `att_dict_list` and `att_dict` ? Can you provide some verifiable code?

Comment: @jpp I have modified op to add more info

Comment: I still don't see `att_dict_list` defined. Can you give an example?

Comment: Also, please include the full traceback.

Comment: @jpp have updated op with info needed